# Inclusion of header files in header file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c, cocoa-touch

This question may look silly, however I am not clear I don't hesitate to ask this question. Including header file in one more header file, Is it a good practice. Usually I guess its not a good approach. In some cases it required to include header files.

```
eg: @property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audio_player;
```

Consider I have property like this, When I include its corresponding header file in .mm file Xcode is showing undeclared error in .h file, so I'm here forced to include its header file in .h file itself. Because of this wherever I am including this class I also include indirectly audio player header file also, it may not require in that class. How can we avoid this. Or I can proceed like this...? Please provide a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to avoid this. It's perfectly legal and idiomatic.

The logic behind this is that you may want to access the `audio_player` property of an instance of your class from another class, and if you didn't do this, then the type of the property would be undeclared.

Comment: I have given forward declaration for this. It is compiling fine. Is it Ok?

Comment: @user1587011 yes, it's also good but only if you don't want to use that property later (i. e. calling methods on it, using its accessors, etc...)

Comment: Forward declaration should be fine as long as you do import the file *somewhere* in your project - for example, forward declare the class in the .h file and import in the .m. Personally I find it just clutters the code a bit and makes it more of a pain to change, but it should be completely fine to do that way.

Answer (score 4):

It's very common to include header files from other header files.

For C and C++ it's common to wrap your header content into an `#ifdef` `#endif` block to avoid multiple declarations (look at any common c/c++ header, including those from the standard library).

In Objective-C the `#ifdef` `#endif` bracketing is generally not necessary as in objective C you generally use `import` instead of `include` and importing a file is guaranteed to happen only once no matter how many times it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I find forward declarations are to be preferred because they reduce compile times when header files are changed, particularly with larger projects where the number of affected .m files otherwise seems to grow geometrically with every linear increase in the number of modified .h files.

Forward declarations also promote code reuse because if you try to separate a project into two separate projects you will find that all the time you "saved" by simply throwing in an import in a convenient place will be offset by the fact that you now have to add/remove imports to reflect the new program structure.  With forward declarations the linkages are clearer and their maintenance is minimized.  Basically excessive #importing promotes unnecessary coupling.